# How to update the multiple file names in request from csv file using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We have a POST api and we can send multiple files in a request.

I created a csv file with all file Names. Its updating same filename each json object.

How can i get the unique filename in json object from csv? Or is there any approch to get unique files from a file?

**Request:**

```
[
   {
        "filePath": "Filename1",
        "orgId": "org123",
        "Domain": "abcd.com",
    },
{
        "filePath": "Filename2",
        "orgId": "org123",
        "Domain": "abcd.com",
    },{
        "filePath": "Filename3",
        "orgId": "org123",
        "Domain": "abcd.com",
    },{
        "filePath": "Filename4",
        "orgId": "org123",
        "Domain": "abcd.com",
    },{
        "filePath": "Filename5",
        "orgId": "org123",
        "Domain": "abcd.com",
    }
]
```

[image: CSV config]

[image: CSV file]

[image: Jmete Sampler]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using CSV Data Set Config, it reads next line on each iteration of each virtual user (or according to [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting), but none of the Sharing Modes allows reading multiple lines in a single shot, moreover you need to pass them into single request somehow.

If you need to create one section like this:

```
{
    "filePath": "filename from CSV here",
    "orgId": "org123",
    "Domain": "abcd.com",
}
```

per line in the CSV file you could do this using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def payload = []

new File('test.csv').readLines().each { line ->
    payload.add([filePath: line, orgId: 'org123', Domain: 'abcd.com'])
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

generated JSON could be accessed as `${payload}` where required

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. I will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple variable names under CSV Data Set Config element(for FileName1,FileName2..etc)and use them.

Comment: I have more than 1000 filenames in a single column, So I am using a single variable. I am looking for a solution is it possible to pick a new row value when we use a variable?

Comment: You can specify 5 File names in single column and use

Comment: I am getting the same file name (first Row) value for all variables. It's not taking 2nd-row value

Comment: share your CSV config element and CSV file

Comment: Added the details to the Question- Guru

Comment: If  filename occurences per request is fixed, Eg :-if 2 times then use 2 config variables Filename1,Filename2 and input the CSV file with 2 names separated by comma.

Comment: Yes, But I have to upload 500 files in a single request. It's difficult to add 500 variables.